# Why are Arrays invariant, but Lists covariant?

Tags: arrays, list, scala, covariance

E.g. why does

```
val list:List[Any] = List[Int](1,2,3)
```

work, but

```
val arr:Array[Any] = Array[Int](1,2,3)
```

fails (because arrays are invariant). What is the desired effect behind this design decision?

Comment: Note that java arrays are covariant, and this may cause a problem when calling java code from scala.

Comment: @incrop - can you please give an example?

Comment: @KevinMeredith 
Integer[] source = {1, 2, 3};  
Number[] target = source;
target[0] = 4;  
target[0] = 3.14; // compiles // but ArrayStoreException at runtime //attempt of heap pollution

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Because it would break type-safety otherwise.
If not, you would be able to do something like this:

```
val arr:Array[Int] = Array[Int](1,2,3)
val arr2:Array[Any] = arr
arr2(0) = 2.54
```

and the compiler can't catch it.

On the other hand, lists are immutable, so you can't add something that is not `Int`

Comment: You mean `Array`, not `List`, do you? With lists, your example won't work (no "update" method in type `List`). With `Array`s, it would be a valid counter example of what you could do, were arrays covariant.

Comment: The credit should go to @sshannin, as i just put an example and rephrase what he said.

Comment: why does `arr2(0)` evaluate to `2.54` in your example, @OpDeCirkel?

Comment: @KevinMeredith, it is not an evaluation, it is the assignment. In the example if arrays in scala were not invariant, we would be apple to add floating point number (2.54 in case of example above) in an Int array. The example highlights the problem if array were not invariant.

Comment: @OpDeCirkel i think it's worth mentioning that another common immutable collection, `Set`, although safe to upcast, is also invariant in its type - this is because a `Set[A]` is also an `A => Boolean`, but functions are contravariant in their arguments. `Set`s can be upcasted either via `Set[Child]().asInstanceOf[Set[Parent]]`, or `Set[Child]().toSet[Parent]` - the first one smells but doesn't create a new collection.

Comment: In Coursera's "Functional Programming Principles in Scala" there is a lecture that tackles precisely this question:
Week 4 - Lecture 4.4 - Variance (Optional)

This link will probably not be functional forever, but in case that someone checks this question soon:
https://es.coursera.org/learn/progfun1/lecture/dnreZ/lecture-4-4-variance-optional

Answer (score 25):

This is because lists are immutable and arrays are mutable.

Comment: The credit should go to @sshannin, as i just put an example and rephrase what he said.

Comment: -1. Why do people upvote answers like this? Without some explanation of why this is relevant you might as well be saying "because `Array` starts with 'A' and `List` starts with 'L'".

Comment: That's a good point, Travis. I upvoted it before I read your comment, and then realized I only upvoted it because I already knew the answer when I got here and this just articulated it concisely. But answers that only work if you already knew the answer aren't all that useful.

Answer (score 9):

The normal answer to give is that mutability combined with covariance would break type safety. For collections, this can be taken as a fundamental truth. But the theory actually applies to any generic type, not just collections like `List` and `Array`, and we don't have to try and reason about mutability at all.

The real answer has to do with the way function types interact with subtyping. The short story is if a type parameter is used as a return type, it is covariant. On the other hand, if a type parameter is used as an argument type, it is contravariant. If it is used both as a return type and as an argument type, it is invariant.

Let's look at the [documentation for `Array[T]`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Array.html). The two obvious methods to look at are for the ones for lookup and update:

```
def apply(i: Int): T
def update(i: Int, x: T): Unit
```

In the first method `T` is a return type, while in the second `T` is an argument type. The rules of variance dictate that `T` must therefore be invariant.

We can compare the [documentation for `List[A]`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html) to see why it is covariant. Confusingly, we would find these methods, which are analogous to the methods for `Array[T]`:

```
def apply(n: Int): A
def ::(x: A): List[A]
```

Since `A` is used as both a return type and as an argument type, we would expect `A` to be invariant just like `T` is for `Array[T]`. However, unlike with `Array[T]`, the documentation is lying to us about the type of `::`. The lie is good enough for most calls to this method, but isn't good enough to decide the variance of `A`. If we expand the documentation for this method and click on "Full Signature", we are shown the truth:

```
def ::[B >: A](x: B): List[B]
```

So `A` does not actually appear as an argument type. Instead, `B` (which can be any supertype of `A`) is the argument type. This does not place any restriction on `A`, so it really can be covariant. Any method on `List[A]` which has `A` as an argument type is a similar lie (we can tell because these methods are marked as `[use case]`).

Comment: You did not explain why "The lie is good enough for most calls to this method", and you did not explain why they chose not to use this lie for Array and make it also covariant.

Comment: If I could +1 this more than once ... the part about the real signature for `::` was priceless

Comment: @rapt there was a decision from `2.8` onward to spare the reader from the nuances of type annotations in collection API and just show the gentler signature that covers the vast majority of use cases. That's why it says `...[A]` and not `...[B >: A]` *only* in the docs and *only* as an aid to be a gentler read. This doesn't mean the actual method signature is the simpler one. The actual method signature is still the more complex one with the correct variance.

Answer (score 7):

The difference is that `List`s are immutable while `Array`s are mutable.

To understand why mutability determines variance, consider making a mutable version of `List` - let's call it `MutableList`. We'll also make use of some example types: a base class `Animal` and 2 subclasses named `Cat` and `Dog`.

```
trait Animal {
  def makeSound: String
}

class Cat extends Animal {
  def makeSound = "meow"
  def jump = // ...
}

class Dog extends Animal {
  def makeSound = "bark"
}
```

Notice that `Cat` has one more method (`jump`) than `Dog`.

Then, define a function that accepts a mutable list of animals and modifies the list:

```
def mindlessFunc(xs: MutableList[Animal]) = {
  xs += new Dog()
}
```

Now, horrible things will happen if you pass a list of cats into the function:

```
val cats = MutableList[Cat](cat1, cat2)
val horror = mindlessFunc(cats)
```

If we were using a careless programming language, this will be ignored during compilation. Nevertheless, our world will not collapse if we only access the list of cats using the following code:

```
cats.foreach(c => c.makeSound)
```

But if we do this:

```
cats.foreach(c => c.jump)
```

A runtime error will occur. With Scala, writing such code is prevented, because the compiler will complain.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, and in fact doesn't mention arrays at all. The OP might infer that the problem comes from the mutability of arrays, but it isn't stated here.

Comment: @csjacobs24 I have added a line at the top of the answer to provide a direct answer to the question. The purpose of the original answer was to explain why it is wrong for mutable lists to be covariant.

Comment: @YuhuanJiang Nice answer , it can be better it you expand it to explain how the problem doesn't happen when list is immutable(default). Also at the beginning of the answer you can start with explaining what covariance really is for the folks who do not know along with the liskov principle. None of the answers here to this important question are comprhensive.