# Liskov Substitution Principle and Arrays invariance

Tags: scala, covariant

The Liskov Substitution Principle tells us that if A is a subtype of B than everything we can do with type B we should be able to do with type A.

So to investigate this further, I create the following:

```
class Animal

class Dog extends Animal

class BlueDog extends Dog
```

I understand why I am not allowed to do

```
val c: Array[Animal] = a
```

as Arrays are not covariant in Scala (like they are in Java).

But, I think I should be able to do:

```
  val a: Array[Dog] = Array(new Dog())
  val b: Array[BlueDog] = a
```

I would expect val b to be ok.
But I get:

```
class Array is invariant in type T. You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ >: ...
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scala: Why are Arrays invariant, but Lists covariant?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684493/scala-why-are-arrays-invariant-but-lists-covariant)

Comment: By the way, why do you expect `val b: Array[BlueDog] = a` to be *sound*?  Even if Arrays were not invariant, you are assigning least specific to the most specific. What you expect to happen if you take element from b and call method defined only on BlueDog?

Answer (score 1):

```
val a: Array[Dog] = Array(new Dog())
val b: Array[BlueDog] = a
```

Is a little strange, since your BlueDog is more strictly then Dog and may have other method.

```
class Animal
class Dog extends Animal
class BlueDog extends Dog {
  def wolf() { println ("I'm a blue dog") }
}
```

Then what should the following code do?

```
val a: Array[Dog] = new Array(new Dog())
val b: Array[BlueDog] = a
b(0).wolf()
```

Well, your Dog in Array `a` does not have `wolf()` method....so it's clearly that you should not assign a parent type to subtype.

That's why the following works:

```
val dog: Dog = new BlueDog
```

But the following doesn't:

```
val blueDog: BlueDog = new Dog
```