# Scala : generics and variable inheritance issue

Tags: scala, generics, inheritance, scala-2.10

I have a curious problem, maybe because my classes' structure is a bit complex, but anyway :

So first I have 2 abstract classes : TestAbstract1 and TestAbstract2.

- **TestAbstract2** takes a type extending TestAbstract1
- **TestAbstract1** declares a val named **valTest** of type TestAbstract2[TestAbstract1] that has to be implemented in child classes

Code :

```
abstract class TestAbstract1 {
    val valTest: TestAbstract2[TestAbstract1]

    def meth1(): List[TestAbstract1] = {
        valTest.meth2()
    }
}

abstract class TestAbstract2[T <: TestAbstract1] {
    def meth2(): List[T] = {
        List()
    }
}
```

Then I have one object **TestObject2** that extends TestAbstract2, and a basic class **Test2** that extends TestAbstract1, and has to implement **valTest** :

```
class Test2 extends TestAbstract1 {
    val valTest: TestAbstract2[Test2] = TestObject2
}

object TestObject2 extends TestAbstract2[Test2] { }
```

The problem is here : when I compile, it tells me :

> [error] overriding value valTest in class TestAbstract1 of type models.test.TestAbstract2[models.test.TestAbstract1];
>
> [error]  value valTest has incompatible type
>
> [error]     val valTest: TestAbstract2[Test2] = TestObject2

I don't know what I am doing wrong, because if I think about polymorphism rules, it should be alright ...

Do you have any idea ? Or maybe even a better way of doing what I want ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your example, `TestAbstract2` is not covariant. Meaning that even if we have

```
Test2 <: TestAbstract1
```

It is not the case that:

```
TestAbstract2[Test2] <: TestAbstract2[TestAbstract1]
```

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684493/why-are-arrays-invariant-but-lists-covariant) if this does not make sense to you.

In your example, `valTest` as declared in `Test2` is of type `TestAbstract2[Test2]` but expected to be `TestAbstract2[TestAbstract1]`, therefore the error.

You have the following options:

1. Declare `TestAbstract2` as covariant:

   ```
   class TestAbstract2[+T <: TestAbstract1]
   ```
2. Declare `valTest` using wildchard types:

   ```
   val valTest: TestAbstract2[_ <: TestAbstract1]
   ```
3. Parametrize `TestAbstract1` on the type of the inner `TestAbstract2`:

   ```
   class TestAbstract1[T <: TestAbstract1[T]] {
     val valTest: TestAbstract2[T]
     // ...
   }
   ```

   Changing `Test2` to:

   ```
   class Test2 extends TestAbstract1[Test2]
   ```

Note that the choice of using F-bounded polymorphism (bounding `T` by a function of itself in `TestAbstract1`) in the third example is somewhat arbitrary here. I just needed some type to put in for the sake of the example, and in your example it works (when looking at the definition of `Test2`). Which of these three versions is the best for you depends on how you want to use these classes.

If this is not sufficient for you, please provide more detail in your questions and we'll gladly help.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working like a charm ! I declared TestAbstract2 as covariant, but in fact, TestAbstract2 extends an other type parameterized class (yes, one more), and I had to use @uncheckedVariance to this declaration. But it's working as expected ;) Again : thank you !

Comment: @Zarkus13 Glad it worked out for you. Take care with using `@uncheckedVariance`! It might allow you to use methods in a way which is not typesafe. (See the link in my answer)