# How do arrays "remember" their types in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, generics, arraylist

Consider the following code:

```
class AA { }

class BB extends AA { }

public class Testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BB[] arr = new BB[10];
        AA[] arr2 = arr;

        BB b = new BB();
        AA a = new AA();
        arr2[0] = a; // ArrayStoreException at runtime
        arr2[1] = b;

        List<BB> listBB = new ArrayList<>();
        List listAA = listBB;
        listAA.add("hello world.txt");

    }
}
```

In the above example, I get the `ArrayStoreException` when I try `arr2[0] = a`. That means the array remembers what type it must accept. But the `List` does not remember them. It simply compiles and runs fine. The `ClassCastException` will be thrown when I retrieve the object `BB`.

So the questions are:

1. How an array remembers its type (I know it's called "reification"). How this happens exactly?
2. And why only arrays are bestowed with this power but not `ArrayList` although it uses an array under its hood.
3. Why can't `ArrayStoreException` be detected at compile time, i.e when I do `arr2[0] = a`, it could cause a compiler error, instead of detecting it at runtime.

Thanks.

Comment: I can only answer 2) Due to type erasure, since behind the scenes you have `Object[]` and no `BB[]`.

Comment: Why did you not use `List<AA> listAA` in the penultimate code line to make the array and list handling examples more similar? (If you answer is "because it did not work", think about why it did not work. ;-))

Comment: Related: [Why are arrays covariant but generics are invariant?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18666710/697449)

Comment: If you declare an `Object[]` array that will accept any object type.  This is the type that's used inside an ArrayList.  The "generic" stuff is just compiler hocus-pocus and has no effect at runtime, other than to instruct the compiler to do the appropriate casts on receiving a value from the generic class..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. The type information for arrays, unlike for generics, is stored at runtime.  This has been part of Java since the beginning of it.  At runtime, a `AA[]` can be distinguished from a `BB[]`, because the JVM knows their types.
2. An `ArrayList` (and the rest of the Collections framework) uses generics, which is subject to type erasure.  At runtime, the generic type parameter is not available, so an `ArrayList<BB>` is indistinguishable from an `ArrayList<AA>`; they are both just `ArrayList`s to the JVM.
3. The compiler only knows that `arr2` is a `AA[]`.  If you have a `AA[]`, the compiler can only assume that it can store an `AA`.  The compiler will not detect a type safety issue in that you are placing an `AA` in what's really a `BB[]` there, because it only sees the `AA[]` reference.  Unlike generics, Java arrays are covariant, in that a `BB[]` is an `AA[]` because a `BB` is an `AA`.  But that introduces the possibility of what you just demonstrated - an `ArrayStoreException`, because the object referred to by `arr2` is really a `BB[]`, which will not handle an `AA` as an element.

Comment: when I do `List<AA> listAA = listBB;` instead of `List listAA = listBB;`, I get compile error. but the raw type for both should be same correct?

Comment: You get the compiler error because Java generics are invariant, unlike arrays.  That is, a `List<BB>` is _not_ a `List<AA>`, even though a `BB` is an `AA`.  This must be caught at compile time, because there is no equivalent of the `ArrayStoreException` for collections.  The JVM cannot catch such an error, so the compiler must prevent it with a compiler error.  See [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p) for more detail.

Answer (score 8):

**1.**
Each time a value is stored into an array, the compiler inserts a check. Then at run-time it validates the type of the value is equal to the run-time type of the array.

**2.**
Generics were introduced. Generics are invariant and can be verified at compile time. (At run-time the generic types are erased).

**3.** 
Here is an example of the failing case (from wikipedia):

```
// a is a single-element array of String
String[] a = new String[1];

// b is an array of Object
Object[] b = a;

// Assign an Integer to b. This would be possible if b really were
// an array of Object, but since it really is an array of String,
// we will get a java.lang.ArrayStoreException.
b[0] = 1;
```

The compiler cannot detect that the third statement will result in an `ArrayStoreException`. With regard to the third statement, the compiler sees that we are adding an Integer to an Object[] array. This is perfectly legal.

**Background / Reasoning** (from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29#Covariant_arrays_in_Java_and_C.23))

> Early versions of Java and C# did not include generics (a.k.a. parametric polymorphism). In such a setting,     making arrays invariant rules out useful polymorphic programs.
>   For example, consider writing a function to shuffle an array, or a function that tests two arrays for equality using the Object.equals method on the elements. The implementation does not depend on the exact type of element stored in the array, so it should be possible to write a single function that works on all types of arrays. It is easy to implement functions of type

```
boolean equalArrays (Object[] a1, Object[] a2);
void shuffleArray(Object[] a);
```

> However, if array types were treated as invariant, it would only be possible to call these functions on an array of exactly the type Object[]. One could not, for example, shuffle an array of strings.
>
> Therefore, both Java and C# treat array types covariantly. For instance, in C# string[] is a subtype of object[], and in Java String[] is a subtype of Object[]

Comment: In the example of failing case, when we ourselves can logically tell that third statement is not legal, the compiler should be able to catch it, but why it does not?

Comment: The compiler knows that `b` is of type `Object[]`. Arrays are covariant and thus can accept a covariant types, e.g. Integer.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays do explicitly remember their type, you can even get it at runtime (array.getClass().getComponentType()).

When storing to an array, the VM will check if the element to be store is assignment compatible with the array's component type. If it isn't, you get ArrayStoreException.

Collections (as ArrayList) do internally declare their backing arrays as Object[], thus they can store anything, even types they are not allowed to store by their generic definition.

Answer (score 1):

3) Whether you do `AA a = new AA();` or `AA a = new BB();`, the compiler does not remember later what you assigned to `a`, only that its declared type is `AA`. However, in the latter case, you can in fact assign the value of `a` to an element of a `BB[]`, so `arr2[0] = a;` should not give you a runtime exception. Thus, the compiler cannot tell in advance. (Besides, you could try nasty things to change the value of `a` at runtime between the respective lines...)

2) Had you used `List<AA> listAA = listBB;`, you would have gotten a compile error. So what you expected from the array example -- compile time detection of an arising impossible assignment -- in fact works with lists! If you leave out the generic type parameter, however, you will get a raw-type list, to which you can assign other lists without reasonable type checks. This is best considered a leftover from early Java, which should be avoided. If you added the following line below you question's code:

```
BB item = listBB.get(0);
```

Do you think it should/will compile? Should/will it run (and, if so, what should be its result)?

The *how* part of 1) probably warrants a separate question.

Comment: when you say the compiler does not remember later what you assgined to `a`, I  can then do `AA a = new Car()`, but that is not allowed

Comment: This has nothing to do with it. `Car` is not an `AA`, so the assignment is simply invalid. The compiler will stop right there, no remembering required.

Comment: It checks whether the assignment is valid, then translates it to bytecode. Nothing is thrown out. Only the information on the declared type is kept. Keeping information on the expected runtime type (e.g. what was assigned) is not usually useful. First, the compiler cannot follow every possible control flow to keep this information up-to-date (ex: the assignment is followed by "if today is thursday, assign something else to `a`" before `a` is used; also, parallel processes). Second, it may not be useful anyway (ex: `a` is not used in any `BB`-related way anywhere).

Comment: so the compiler looks to see whether what is assigned is valid or not but throws out when it goes to next line..?

Comment: The bytecode will have information about the variable and its type; but no objects are created in heap correct?

Answer (score 1):

1. Simply speaking: arrays are a class. `BB[]` does not extend `AA[]` even though `BB` extends `AA`.
2. In the early days pre-generics.  `ArrayList`s held Objects.  so anything could be held in an `ArrayList`.  If you had an Array of `Object`, you could play the same game.  Now with generics you can specify an `ArrayList` with a specific type like `ArrayList<String>`.
3. actually the problem is on line 2:

   ```
   AA[] arr2=arr;
   ```

Let's make the problem a little easier.  You have a vehicle class and a bike and a car class that extends vehicle.  You can not have

```
Bike b=new Bike()
Car c=b;
```

arr2 is an array and arr is an array, but the class is different.  Does that help?

Comment: It sounds like what you want is ArrayList<? extends AA>