# how arraylist is heterogeneous if it internally uses Object[] Array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

arraylist internally uses Object[] Array which is homogeneous then how arraylist is heterogeneous

The following throws an exception when running:

```
Object[] array = new String[3];
array[0] = "a";
array[1] = 1;   // throws java.lang.ArrayStoreException
```

unlike the following which compiles and runs without problem

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("a");
list.add(1);    // works
list.add(new Object());  // works
```

Comment: autoboxing/unboxing

Comment: but 1 is not string

Comment: `new String[3]` can't contain anything other than `String`s

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do arrays "remember" their types in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21711772/how-do-arrays-remember-their-types-in-java)

Comment: You really shouldn't use raw types (such as `ArrayList list`) in any new code. If you had declared `list` properly, you would get compilation errors when trying to add the wrong type of element to the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The backing array of an [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) is an `Object[]` (i.e. the element type of that array is the [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) class, not any sub-class of [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)), so you can put any reference type (as well as primitives, which get auto-boxed to their corresponding wrapper type) in it.

The following would not throw an exception:

```
Object[] array = new Object[3];
array[0] = "a";
array[1] = 1;
```

You can see the initialization of the backing array in the [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) constructor:

```
public ArrayList(int initialCapacity) {
    if (initialCapacity > 0) {
        this.elementData = new Object[initialCapacity]; // here
    } else if (initialCapacity == 0) {
        this.elementData = EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal Capacity: "+
                                           initialCapacity);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generics are compile-time feature of the Java Language. At runtime, all defined generic types are considered to be of `Object` type. Therefore, using `Object[]` as the backing supporting list makes perfect sense.

Doing these two compiles to the same thing (same bytecode):

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

On the other hand, array types are consistent through compile and run time. These will produce different bytecode after compiling:

```
String[] arr = new String[];
Integer[] arr = new Integer[];
```

Answer (score 0):

since it is holding Object which is parent of all classes so eventually we are make homogeneous to heterogeneous. And this is is not the ideal way to define arraylist. But technically we can do.