# How to instantiate nested Lists in java? list<list<Integer>>

Tags: java, generics

Edit:

Thanks for pointing me to the generic type invariant discussion. Looks like the problem is at the generic type part. `List<E>` where `E` is a generic type, in this case, `E` is `List<Integer>` which is an interface with `Integer`s as elements, and `LinkedList<integer>` is an object (with `Integer`s as elements) not an interface. So it does not work.

So this needs to be done in two steps. Am I understanding this correctly?

```
List<List<Integer>> outter_list = new LinkedList<List<Integer>>();
List<Integer> innder_list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
```

It's somewhat different than the parent child classes case. Since in this case, we are comparing an object implements the interface to the underlying interface.

I hope they would make this easier...

Original question:

This is from questions on LeetCode. A question may require you to write a method that returns a `List<Integer>`. I could do:

```
LinkedList<Integer> list;
//code to construct the list here.
return list;
```

And it works fine.

There is a question that requires to return a `List<List<Integer>>` and below

```
LinkedList<LinkedList<Integer>> list;
//code to construct the lists here.
return list;
```

this would not work and resulted in incompatible type error. I am curious why.

I had to use `LinkedList<List<Integer>>` in the first line of declaration in order for it to work. As to my understanding the `LinkedList<LinkedList<Integer>> list;` is a perfect fine object that implements `List<List<Integer>>`. Why is it incompatible?

Comment: Generics are not covarient, Check this question once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666710/why-are-arrays-covariant-but-generics-are-invariant

Comment: please let me know if I am understanding this correctly as in my later Edit. Thanks,

Comment: Your understanding is correct, you need to do this because of the type erasure. If you want your outer list to hold any type of `List`, then you need to use wildcards something like `List<? super List<Integer>>`. Read more on type erasure and wildcard generics

Comment: thanks for replying, @Rp- . This was for leetCode question so I was not supposed to modify the return type. But it is good to be aware of the possibility of the wildcard.