# How does the compiler differentiate <? extends Number> from <Number> when they both seemingly get compiled to the same thing after type erasure?

Tags: java, covariance, type-erasure

I'm trying to understand [java generic covariancy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666710/why-are-arrays-covariant-but-generics-are-invariant), and I understand why

```
List<Number> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Integer = list.get(0);
```

is disallowed, so that a float isn't put into list and later cause issues. I believe type erasure would compile this down to:

```
List list = new ArrayList();
Integer = (Integer) list.get(0);
```

This is allowed:

```
List<? extends Number> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Integer = list.get(0);
```

Doesn't this compile down to the same thing after type erasure?
How does the wildcard help the compiler in enforcing that a float isn't put into the list when it holds Integers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have `List<? extends Number> list`, you just cannot put *anything* into the resulting list. Your list is the "list containing some objects which extend `Number`", so calling `add()` with any argument is not compatible with this type. So this is how compiler controls whether you don't put floats: it does not allow to put anything.

Usually you change type to `List<? extends Number>` only at the places where you are not going to modify the list anymore and want just to read it.

Comment: worth mentioning [PECS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs) principle

Comment: It makes sense! What if I do ```<E extends Number>```? Would that still be the same?

Comment: @Siddhartha, in this case you will be able to put the objects of type `E`. E.g. `static <E extends Number> void doPut(List<E> list, E obj) {list.add(obj);}` will work.

Answer (score 1):

Very well answered by Tagir and I would like to add few more points. 
 First of all the following will not even compile:

```
List<? extends Number> list = new List<Integer>();
```

I hope you know `List` is an interface. So now we have:

```
List<? extends Number> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Here `list` is a reference of type `List<? extends Number>` and it simply means it can refer to a list in which every element **IS** `Number` or more specifically every element extends class `Number` so it means all the following are permissible:

```
list = new ArrayList<Float>();
list = new ArrayList<Long>();
```

But we can not instantiate as a list of `Object` as `Object` is not `Number`.

```
list = new ArrayList<Object>(); // compile time error
```

Now when we take element out of this list we know only one thing for sure that it is going to be a `Number` and it means not sure but it can be `Integer`or `Long` as well. So we need casting as:

```
Integer integer = (Integer) list.get(0);
Float floatValue = (Float) list.get(0);
Number number = list.get(0); // no casting if assigning it to Number
```

This is mainly useful when we are producing the elements and not consuming them (check [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs)). For example useful in printing the elements but not useful when you want to add any element in it as it will not even compile.

```
private static void printMe(List<? extends Number> numbers) {
        for(Number number : numbers) {
            System.out.println(number);
        }
}
```

This can be invoked then as:

```
List<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<>();
integerList.add(10);integerList.add(20);integerList.add(30);
printMe(integerList);

List<Long> longList = new ArrayList<>();
longList.add((long) 4.5);longList.add((long) 6.5);longList.add((long) 7.5);
printMe(longList);
```

This will simply print the elements in each list.

Comment: That was a mistake by me, it should've been ArrayList and not List. Fixed. Thanks for your answer.