# Why can't the Integer.class object be added to a Collection<Class<Number>> object?

Tags: java, class, generics

I thought to have a quite good understanding of generics but just can't figure out why I get a compiler error here:

```
    Collection<Class<Number>> ncs = new HashSet<Class<Number>>();               
    ncs.add(Number.class);      //ok!
    ncs.add(Integer.class);     //compiler error here
```

Would be nice if anyone could explain this. :)

Edit: I understand why it's not possible to add a `Integer.class` object to a Collection> as it is pointed out in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p). But I don't understand why my example is the same. Of course this doesn't work:

```
Collection<? extends Number> ns = new HashSet<Number>();
ns.add(new Integer(1)); //compiler error here
```

But this does:

```
Collection<Number> ns = new HashSet<Number>();
ns.add(new Integer(1)); //ok!
```

As far as I understand my initial code uses the same concepts.

Comment: The type of `Integer.class` is `Class<Integer>`, which is not compatible with `Class<Number>`.

Comment: Try `Class<? extends Number>`

Comment: I just edited the question as I think it's another one than the one marked as duplicate.

Comment: No, it's the same. A `Class<Integer>` is not a `Class<Number>` just as a `List<Dog>` is not a `List<Animal>`.

Comment: This is unrelated to the `Collection` you're trying to add to. You can remove that entirely and the problem would be the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given classes `X`, `Y`, and `Z`, where `X` is a subclass of `Y`, `X<Z>` is a subclass of `Y<Z>` (e.g. what you've done with `Collection` and `HashSet`), but `Z<X>` is not a subclass of `Z<Y>`, so a `Class<Integer>` instance is not a `Class<Number>` and you can't put the former in a collection of the latter. For the latter you need wildcards, as romeara has shown.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666710/why-are-arrays-covariant-but-generics-are-invariant).

Comment: That is correct but not the answer to his problem.

Comment: @sim It may not be the solution, but it definitely answers the question of *why I get a compiler error here*.

Comment: @sim Why not? It perfectly answers the question ...

Comment: The problem is a missunderstanding, Integer is a subclass of Number. But Integer.class is not a subclass of Number.class, Thus an Integer.class "object" cannot be added to a generic list of type Number.class.

Comment: @sim how is that not exactly what I've written?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to declare the collection as

```
Collection<Class<? extends Number>> ncs = new HashSet<Class<? extends Number>>();
```

because of what Alex Hall explained in his answer:

> `Given classes X, Y, and Z, where X is a subclass of Y, X<Z> is a subclass of Y<Z>, but Z<X> is not a subclass of Z<Y>`

Comment: This has nothing to do with erasure.

Comment: @shmosel but the suggestion is still correct, right?

Comment: @AlexHall yes it is.

Comment: @AlexHall I did not.

Comment: @AlexHall Although the suggestion is correct, the explaining sentence is so wrong that it leads to the wrong direction and makes it a bad answer. Hence the downvote. I also did that ... and right now I removed my downvote because of the edit.

Comment: Now I'm stuck in a recursive loop.

Comment: I have fixed the explanation/terminology to have the correct explanation for future finders of the question. Thank you for pointing out the error!