# Why can't I use an ArrayList<Subclass> as an argument in a method that uses an ArrayList<Superclass>?

Tags: java, arraylist

See title. I can't figure out why it doesn't work.

Example of non-working code:

```
displayList(subclassArrayList);
```

...gives me

```
"incompatible types: ArrayList<B> cannot be converted to ArrayList<A>"
```

My classes:

```
public static class A{
    int someAttribute = 0;
    A(){}
}
public static class B extends A{
    int someOtherAttribute = 2;
    B(int value){
        this.someOtherAttribute = value;
    }
}
```

Somewhere in main:

```
ArrayList<B> subclassArrayList = new ArrayList();
subclassArrayList.add(new B(3));
subclassArrayList.add(new B(5));
subclassArrayList.add(new B(7));
```

The offending function:

```
void displayList(ArrayList<A> superclassList){
    for(A item : superclassList){
        System.out.print(item.someOtherAttribute);
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
}
```

However, I've found that I'm able to do this with no apparent problems.

```
ArrayList<A> superclassArrayList = new ArrayList();
superclassArrayList.addAll(subclassArrayList);
displayList(superclassArrayList);
```

What exactly is my code doing behind the scenes, here?

Comment: Because you declare  `ArrayList<B>` and in your loop you use another Type `A`, 

so try to change this :

`for(A item : superclassList){`

to this :

`for(B item : superclassList){`

Comment: Another duplicate question: [Why are arrays covariant but generics are invariant?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666710/why-are-arrays-covariant-but-generics-are-invariant)