# Does Java array covariance violate Liskov Substitution Principle?

Tags: generics, covariance, language-design, solid-principles, liskov-substitution-principle

I was reading why array covariance in Java is bad ([Why are arrays covariant but generics are invariant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666710/why-are-arrays-covariant-but-generics-are-invariant)).  If a `Dog` is a subtype of `Animal`, then a `Dog[]` is a subtype of `Animal[]`.  This is a problem because things like this can be done:

```
Animal[] animals = new Dog[1];
animals[0] = new Cat();
```

This is different from generics which were implemented 'correctly'.  A `List<Dog>` is not a subtype of `List<Animal>`

I was trying to understand the essence of why it is bad and had just read about LSP.  Did it violate the LSP in any way?  There doesn't seem to be a clear violation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Did it violate the LSP in any way?

Yes.

> There doesn't seem to be a clear violation.

Your own example is a violation. The following code works fine:

```
Animal[] animals = new Animal[1];
animals[0] = new Cat();
```

But if now replace the `Animal[]` with its subtype `Dog[]`, the code no longer works (that is, it causes an exception when it didn't previously). So the type `Dog[]` can't be used everywhere where its supertype `Animal[]` can be used and that violates the LSP.

To put this in the LSP's wording: If we consider the property "`new Cat()` can be assigned as an element", the type `Animal[]` fulfils this property, but its subtype `Dog[]` does not.