# what is the difference between Array and Array[Type] in Scala?

Tags: scala

I tried to compile and run the following Scala source code:

```scala
class People(val name: String)
class Student(studentName: String) extends People(studentName)

def getNames(array: Array[People]) = { array.map(_.name) }

getNames(Array[Student](new Student("Mike"), new Student("Tom")))
```

I got error message:

```
Name: Compile Error
Message: <console>:30: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Array[Student]
 required: Array[People]
Note: Student <: People, but class Array is invariant in type T.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: People`. (SLS 3.2.10)
       getNames(Array[Student](new Student("Mike"), new Student("Tom")))
```

It's as expected because Array[Student] is not a subtype of Array[People].

Then I updated

```scala
getNames(Array[Student](new Student("Mike"), new Student("Tom")))
```

to

```scala
getNames(Array(new Student("Mike"), new Student("Tom")))
```

The error was gone. So I'm wondering in Scala what is the difference between Array and Array[Type], especially when it's passed as a method parameter.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Scala arrays don't repeat the [covariance mistake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666710/why-are-arrays-covariant-but-generics-are-invariant) of Java. In Java you can do:

```
Student[] students = new Student[10];
Person[] people = students; // ok in Java arrays are covariant
people[1] = new Person(); // RuntimeException in Java!!
```

Scala is safer than that (like Java generic collections).

You should always use the specific version of collections in order to get better type safety. Your `Array` example detects the generic parameter from the function call - which is `Array[Student]`.

Comment: Thanks much for your answer, it does help!

Comment: I'm sorry, but the second part of this answer is wrong.  You're not getting a "non-generic" array, you're getting an `Array[People]`, because the expected type of the expression is supplied by the `getNames` method.