# Creating heterogenous list of lists in Java

Tags: java, guava

I have the following code

```
        List<Integer> startnodes = ImmutableList.of(397251,519504,539122,539123,539124,539125);
        List<Integer> endnodes = ImmutableList.of(539126,539127,539142,539143,539144,539145);
        List<String> rp = ImmutableList.of("Knows","Knows","Knows","Knows2","Knows2","Knows2");
        Map<String,Value> parameters =
                  ImmutableMap.of("rels",ImmutableList.of(startnodes,endnodes,rp));
```

The compiler throws the following error at the last line.

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from ImmutableMap<String,ImmutableList<List<? 
extends Object&Comparable<?>&Serializable>>> to Map<String,Value>
```

My main confusion is that the value for the key here is a heterogenous list, so what should be the type of the key to satisfy the compiler?. I am relatively new to Java and any suggestions are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: What is `Value`? Java doesn't have .net like value types.

Comment: @Oleg is right, you need to do something like...  "Map<String,List<Integer>> parameters = ...."

Comment: Apologize. I am not clear on what the error message means and hence the confusion.  My main confusion is that the value for the key here is a heterogenous list, so what should be the type of the key to satisfy the compiler?

Comment: replace `Map<String,Value>` with `Map<String,List<Integer>>`

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work as rp here is a string list. I get the following error with the above suggestion.

Type mismatch: cannot convert from ImmutableMap<String,ImmutableList<List<? extends Object&Comparable<?>&Serializable>>> to Map<String,List<Integer>>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ImmutableList.of(startnodes,endnodes,rp)` needs to infer a type that will satisfy both `List<Integer>` and `List<String>` because generics in Java are [invariant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666710/why-are-arrays-covariant-but-generics-are-invariant) the only type that satisfies it is `List<?>`. So you can assign it to:

```
List<List<?>> list = ImmutableList.of(startnodes,endnodes,rp);
```

And your `Map` needs to be defined as:

```
Map<String,List<List<?>>> parameters = ImmutableMap.of("rels",ImmutableList.of(startnodes,endnodes,rp));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make your lists of the same type by using `ImmutableList.<Object>of(397251,519504,....)`. This way you'd get a homogeneous `ImmutableList<ImmutableList<Object>>`, which is possibly slighly less confusing than using wildcards.

However, this all shows that a `List` is not the proper solution to your problem. What about creating a tiny class? Using Lombok, you need just

```
@lombok.Value public class Something {
    private final ImmutableList<Integer> startNodes;
    private final ImmutableList<Integer> endNodes;
    private final ImmutableList<String> rp;
}
```

Without Lombok, you'd need to write quite some boilerplate, but that possibly still worth it, as dealing with heterogeneous Lists is pain.

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't thought about this approach, will consider it carefully.