# Base service for Custom JPA Data Repository

Tags: java, generics, spring-data-jpa

> I've implemented a custom JPA repository as :

```
public class BaseEntity{...}

public class DerivedEntity extends BaseEntity{...}

@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseRepository<T extends BaseEntity> extends JpaRepository<T, ID>{
//some common method
}

@Repository
public interface DerivedRepository extends BaseRepository<DerivedEntity>{
}
```

> Now, I want created a common data-service :

```
public class CommonService{

private BaseRepository<? extends BaseEntity> baseRepository;


  //wants to use common method by passing derivedRepository
  public CommonService(BaseRepository<? extends BaseEntity>  derivedRepository) {
    this.baseRepository=derivedRepository;
  }

}
```

Now,Somewhere in the code I want to use save method:

```
public void foo(BaseEntity entity ) {
    baseRepository.save(entity);
    ...
    ...
  }
```

> I'm getting compile time error:
>
> can not resolve save

How to resolve this issue and design ?
Whats the best way to design a common data service by using common data repository ?

Comment: Can you clarify the requirements a bit?  Are you saying you want a single service that is agnostic to the entity type that will invoke the appropriate repository for that entity?  Meaning there is still 1 repository class per entity?

Comment: Yes, I want a base service which is agonistic of entity type.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [PECS rule](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397/187808): Producer Extends, Consumer Super. This is an acronym that helps us to memorize when we should use `super` and when we should use `extends`. In this case the `save()` method is a consumer. It receives an object, but does not return it. So it should be `super` - and it compiles:

```
private BaseRepository<? super BaseEntity> baseRepository;
// ...
public void foo(BaseEntity entity ) {
    baseRepository.save(entity);
}
```

However, the [`JpaRepository`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html) has Producer methods too, like `findAll()`. If your `CommonService` uses that too, then this `private BaseRepository<? super BaseEntity> baseRepository;` is going to be useless.

There is a workaround too: you can specify an entity type at service level, and be more flexible at method level:

```
public static class CommonService {

    private BaseRepository<BaseEntity> baseRepository;

    public CommonService(BaseRepository<BaseEntity> derivedRepository) {
        this.baseRepository = derivedRepository;
    }

    // here you can accept any subtype you want
    public <T extends BaseEntity> void foo(T entity) {
        baseRepository.save(entity);
    }

    // you can be flexible here
    public List<? super BaseEntity> bar() {
        return baseRepository.findAll();
    }

}
```

Unfortunately, most of these `extends` and `super` and `?` signs make the life difficult for the users of this code. I suggest to keep it as simple as possible. When this is not sufficient, then you can play with the generics until you figure out a solution ***for your needs***. This would be the simplest solution:

```
    // accepts subclasses of BaseEntity
    public void foo(BaseEntity entity) {
        baseRepository.save(entity);
    }

    // reutrns a List<BaseEntity>. The _items_ of the list might be subclasses of BaseEntity.
    public List<BaseEntity> bar() {
        return baseRepository.findAll();
    }
```

An implementation note:

The following line does not define the `ID` type. That would something like `Integer` or `Long` - a field of `BaseEntity`.

```
public static interface BaseRepository<T extends BaseEntity> extends JpaRepository<T, ID>
```

Comment: The return type of bar() method is List<BaseEntity> .So the caller of the service have downcast the the list as:(List<DerivedEntity >) ((List<?>)commonService.bar();

Comment: You can't downcast lists that way. Java generics are invariant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666710/why-are-arrays-covariant-but-generics-are-invariant Moreover, the items aren't always necessarily `DerivedEntity`-es. On the other hand, you can downcast the items, if necessary.