# java cast Map<String, String> to Object

Tags: java, object

Have a function that takes an `Object` type as parameter, I want to use this function by passing a `Map<String, String>` variable. Unfortunately got complaints for that. Is there a way to cast `Map<String, String>` to `Object`? I thought any type of class can be automatically casted to Object since Object is the super class of everything.

This is the code:

```
private GeometryWithTags getRouteGeometryWithTags(Route route)
{
    Map<String, Map<String, String>> edgesTags = new HashMap<>();
        Iterator<Edge> edgeIterator = route.iterator();
        while (edgeIterator.hasNext())
        {
            Edge edge = edgeIterator.next();
            edgesTags.put(new Long(edge.getIdentifier()).toString(), edge.getTags());
        }
        return new GeometryWithTags(route.asPolyLine(), edgesTags);
    }
```

> error: incompatible types: Map> cannot be converted to Map
>               return new GeometryWithTags(route.asPolyLine(), edgesTags);

Comment: Yes - that will work (although the need to do it is suspect).  What is the related code and complaint/error?

Comment: Please paste the code here.

Comment: Show us your code and your error. Casting *to* object should work automatically, so I'm not sure exactly what you mean right now.

Comment: Everything in Java is an Object (subclass to be exact) so you can cast everything to Object

Comment: Just updated with the codes.

Comment: wouldn't Map<String,String> be casted to Object automatically?

Comment: What you're asking is why generics are not *covariant* then. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666710/why-are-arrays-covariant-but-generics-are-invariant. In summation, you can add `Integer` to a `Map<String, Object>` but not to a `Map<String, String>`, so they aren't strict subclasses since `Map` is not read-only.

Answer (score 0):

The reason `Map<String, Map<String, String>>` can't be converted to `Map<String, Object>` is that the latter can do things the former can't. Consider

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> myStringMap = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Object> myObjectMap = myStringMap; // Not allowed, but suppose it were
myObjectMap.put("key", new Integer(10));
// Now myStringMap contains an integer,
// which is decidedly *not* a Map<String, String>
```

If this were allowed, then the `.put` call would fail at runtime, so this sort of situation is disallowed by the type system. If `GeometryWithTags` is a class you control and it actually never adds anything to the map, you should use the [PECS pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super)

```
GeometryWithTags(Map<String, ? extends Object> map) { ... }
```

Now we have a map that can have any value type, but we're guaranteed that we can't add anything (since the `?` could be incompatible with the added value).

If `GeometryWithTags` needs to be able to modify the map, or if you don't have control over the class, then you need to actually make a `Map<String, Object>` initially.