# Generic methods. Multiple arguments match

Tags: java, generics

I cant figure out why does this code work without error.

```
static <T> int compare(T t1, T t2) {
    return 0;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    compare(new Thread(), new StringBuilder());
}
```

Because when we have something like this:

```
static <T> void fromArrayToCollection(T[] a, Collection<T> c) {
    return;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    fromArrayToCollection(new Thread[] {}, new ArrayList<StringBuilder>()); // error
}
```

We have an error.
Why doesn't compiler check match of both arguments in first example? Sorry for stupid question.

Comment: Generics are invariant, not covariant. This means that `List<Dog>` can not be applied to `List<Animal>` (invariant). But `Dog` can be applied to `Animal` (covariant)

Comment: That is because **generics are invariant**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Generics are invariant

Generics are **invariant**, not **covariant**.

This means that, while you can do something like this:

```
Dog dog = new Dog();
Animal animal = dog; // Dog works for Animal, classes are covariant
```

You can not do this:

```
List<Dog> dogs = List.of(new Dog());
List<Animal> animals = dogs; // Error, generics are invariant
```

So `List<Dog>` is **not** of type `List<Animal>`. But `Dog` is of type `Animal`.

Of course this makes sense, since `animals` would accept `Cat`s, but `dogs` not.

---

### Explanation

In your first code, you did not specify the type to use, such as:

```
compare<Foo>(...)
```

so you let the compiler deduce the type. It searches a type which `Thread` and `StringBuilder` have in common, which is `Object`.

So `T` resolves to `Object` there, which is fine:

```
static int compare(Object t1, Object t2) {
    return 0;
}
```

In your second example it can not pick `Object`, because `Collection<Object>` behaves different to `Collection<StringBuilder>`, since generics are **invariant**. So it is unable to find a type that matches, thus an error occurs.

Also see [Why are arrays covariant but generics are invariant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666710/why-are-arrays-covariant-but-generics-are-invariant).

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to add that a simple change in the second code snippet would correct the error:

```
static <T> void fromArrayToCollection(T[] a, Collection<? extends T> c) { ... }
                                                             ^
```

Now, the Java compiler will infer the `Object` again:

```
fromArrayToCollection(new Thread[]{}, new ArrayList<StringBuilder>());
```

Also, you can add the type argument explicitly:

```
Main.<Object>fromArrayToCollection(new Thread[]{}, new ArrayList<StringBuilder>());
        ^
```

`T => Object`:

```
static void fromArrayToCollection(Object[] a, Collection<? extends Object> c) { ... }
```

Further reading: [Upper Bounded Wildcards](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html).