# Scala - Generic type does not type check

Tags: scala, generics, typechecking

I am trying to understand my mistake in implementing generics. I have a trait which defines a method that returns a reference with an upper type bound of the trait. How ever a var reference to an implementation of the trait fails to type check  with `Expression of type Capability[Class] doesn't conform to expected type Capability[Trait]`

Here is the code:

```
trait IAITask {
  def taskTypeReference[T >: IAITask]: Capability[T]
}

object Tasks {
   var Walk: Capability[Walk] = _
}

class Walk extends IAITask {
  override def taskTypeReference[T >: IAITask]: Capability[IAITask] = Tasks.Walk //This line does not type check
}
```

Comment: What is the variance annotation on `Capability`?

Comment: This is a Java class `public class Capability<T>` @SilvioMayolo

Comment: This would compile if `Capability` were covariant on its type parameter, but [Java generics are invariant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18666710/4993128).

Answer (score 1):

If it's a Java interface, then you might want to try to imitate Java's use-site variance by wildcards:

```
trait Capability[A]

trait IAITask {
  def taskTypeReference: Capability[_ <: IAITask]
}

object Tasks {
   var Walk: Capability[Walk] = _
}

class Walk extends IAITask {
  override def taskTypeReference: Capability[_ <: IAITask] = Tasks.Walk
}
```