# Merge map of collections

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to better understand generics in Java and therefore wrote a generic method that merges two maps of collections. (Please ignore for the moment that it creates a hard-coded `ArrayList`.)

```
public static <E, K> void  mergeMaps(Map<K, Collection<E>> receivingMap, Map<K, Collection<E>> givingMap) {
    for (Map.Entry<K, Collection<E>> entry : givingMap.entrySet()) {
        Collection<E> someCollection = receivingMap.computeIfAbsent(entry.getKey(), k -> new ArrayList<E>());
        someCollection.addAll(entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

My goal is that the `mergeMaps` function is able to merge maps (of the same type) whose values can be arbitrary collections (`ArrayList`,`LinkedHashMap`,...).

However, when I try to merge let's say two instances of `Map<Integer, ArrayList<String>>` I get a compile-time error but I do not quite understand what the compiler is telling me.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Integer, ArrayList<String>> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Integer, ArrayList<String>> map2 = new HashMap<>();
    mergeMaps(map1, map2); // <-- compile error
}
```

What is wrong here and how can I fix it?

```
Error:(9, 9) java: method mergeMaps in class CollectionUtil cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.util.Map<K,java.util.Collection<E>>,java.util.Map<K,java.util.Collection<E>>
  found: java.util.Map<java.lang.Integer,java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>>,java.util.Map<java.lang.Integer,java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>>
  reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) E,K
    (argument mismatch; java.util.Map<java.lang.Integer,java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>> cannot be converted to java.util.Map<K,java.util.Collection<E>>)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you [edit] your post to include the compiler error.

Comment: I added the compiler error. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the signature of the method is

```
<E, K> void  mergeMaps(Map<K, Collection<E>> receivingMap, 
                       Map<K, Collection<E>> givingMap)
```

Then a call using `Map<Integer, List<String>>` as argument types is invalid because `Collection` is not a generic type parameter of the `mergeMaps` method.

Why is this a problem? With generics, `Map<Integer, List<String>>` cannot be assigned to a `Map<Integer, Collection<String>>` variable (or passed as a method argument in that manner). This is because generic types are invariant (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666710/why-are-arrays-covariant-but-generics-are-invariant) for more info. In short, that means `List<Integer>` is not necessarily compatible with any `List<Number>`, although a `ArrayList<Number>` is compatible with `List<Number>` ).

In other words, the concrete arguments must be of type `Map<Integer, Collection<String>>`. This leads to your first solution:

```
//Solution 1: change your arguments to Map<Integer, Collection<String>>:
Map<Integer, Collection<String>> map1 = new HashMap<>();
Map<Integer, Collection<String>> map2 = new HashMap<>();
mergeMaps(map1, map2);
```

If you want to allow calls with parameters of type `Map<Integer, List<String>>`, then you have to change your target method to introduce a generic parameter around the map value:

```
public static <E, K, C extends Collection<E>> void 
             mergeMaps2(Map<K, C> receivingMap, Map<K, C> givingMap) {
    for (Map.Entry<K, C> entry : givingMap.entrySet()) {
        Collection<E> someCollection = receivingMap.computeIfAbsent(entry.getKey(), 
                                         k -> (C) new ArrayList<E>());
        someCollection.addAll(entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

And that can be called with maps where the value is declared as a subtype of `Collection<E>` (as long as the `Collection` type is the same in both arguments):

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> map1 = new HashMap<>();
Map<Integer, List<String>> map2 = new HashMap<>();
mergeMaps2(map1, map2);

Map<Integer, Set<String>> map1 = new HashMap<>();
Map<Integer, Set<String>> map2 = new HashMap<>();
mergeMaps2(map1, map2);
```

---

*Side note (or digression)*

Now, when you compile this, you have a further problem: there's a compiler warning on this line:

```
Collection<E> someCollection = 
    receivingMap.computeIfAbsent(entry.getKey(), k -> (C) new ArrayList<E>());
```

Claiming that `(C) new ArrayList<E>()` is an unchecked cast. Why this? Let's look at the above example calls (I added the two advisedly):

Call 1:

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> map1 = new HashMap<>();
Map<Integer, List<String>> map2 = new HashMap<>();
mergeMaps2(map1, map2);
```

In this example, `receivingMap.computeIfAbsent(entry.getKey(), k -> (C) new ArrayList<E>())` means to add an instance of `ArrayList<String>` as a value to the map. As the actual object **is** of a type that is compatible with the caller's declared type (`List<String>`), things are OK.

Now, what do you think this will do?

Call 2:

```
Map<Integer, Set<String>> map1 = new HashMap<>();
Map<Integer, Set<String>> map2 = new HashMap<>();
mergeMaps2(map1, map2);
```

In this case too, *unfortunately*, `receivingMap.computeIfAbsent(entry.getKey(), k -> (C) new ArrayList<E>())` will still try to add an `ArrayList<String>`, which happens to be incompatible with the caller's expected value type (`Set<String>`).

The compiler can't be sure that the cast `(C) new ArrayList<E>()` will always be correct in the context of the concrete type arguments. It gives up, but issues a warning to alert the developer.

Dealing with this is actually a tricky problem. You need to know what type to instantiate, but your method parameters won't allow you to do so because you can't just run `new C()`. Your own requirements and design will determine the correct solution, but I'll end with one possible solution:

```
public static <E, K, C extends Collection<E>> void 
    mergeMaps2(Map<K, C> receivingMap, 
               Map<K, C> givingMap, 
               Supplier<C> collectionCreator) {
    for (Map.Entry<K, C> entry : givingMap.entrySet()) {
        Collection<E> someCollection = receivingMap.computeIfAbsent(entry.getKey(),
                        k -> collectionCreator.get());
        someCollection.addAll(entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says `java.util.List<java.lang.String>> cannot be converted to java.util.Map<K,java.util.Collection<E>>)`

You have to modify your method:

```
public static <E, K> void  mergeMaps(Map<K, List<E>> receivingMap, Map<K, List<E>> givingMap) {
    for (Map.Entry<K, List<E>> entry : givingMap.entrySet()) {
        Collection<E> someCollection = receivingMap.computeIfAbsent(entry.getKey(), k -> new ArrayList<E>());
        someCollection.addAll(entry.getValue());
    }
}
```