# Java syntax of Class<? extends T[]>

Tags: java, generics

The following code is from `Arrays` class:

http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/Arrays-source.html

```
  public static <T,U> T[] copyOfRange(U[] original, int from, int to,
                      Class<? extends T[]> newType)
  {
    if (from > to)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("The initial index is after " +
                     "the final index.");
    T[] newArray = (T[]) Array.newInstance(newType.getComponentType(),
                       to - from);
    if (to > original.length)
      {
    System.arraycopy(original, from, newArray, 0,
             original.length - from);
    fill(newArray, original.length, newArray.length, null);
      }
    else
      System.arraycopy(original, from, newArray, 0, to - from);
    return newArray;
  }
```

I'm baffled by the `Class<? extends T[]>` part, how can `T[]` be extended? As far as I know there's no such array like `K[]` that is subtype of `T[]` even though `K extends T`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because unlike other objects, arrays in java are **covariant**. As to why arrays have this special property, I am not sure but the question has been answered on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666710/why-are-arrays-covariant-but-generics-are-invariant) .

Comment: Thanks! I again got confused with array/list subtyping