# why array of strings can be assigned to array of objects but arraylist of strings cannot be assigned to arraylist of object?

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

Why somethig like line#3 is allowed and line #6 is not allowed in java?

```
Object[] object= new Object[100];
String[] string= new String[100];
object=string; //line #3
List<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
objectList=stringList;// line #6 [Error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<String> to List<Object>]
```

Comment: String is object, Object is not String.

Comment: @ThomasKläger Hi, I am noob in Java, I understood the behavior in case of generics but i am not able understand it in terms of arrays?

Comment: For the question about arrays read https://stackoverflow.com/a/18666878/5646962 - it explains why arrays where defined this way.

Comment: @ThomasKläger Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because arrays are covariant and `String[]` is a sub type of `Object[]`, hence the assignment `object = string;` is legal. But what if you do this:

```
object[0] = 1;
```

The statement compiles fine, but when you run it you get this error.

> java.lang.ArrayStoreException: java.lang.Integer

On the contrary, parameterized types are invariant. So, `List<String>` is neither a subtype nor a supertype of `List<Object>` and your compiler starts complaining at the site of assignment `objectList = stringList;`. But, if you need to make parameterized types covariant while maintaining type safety, you can use wildcards. For an instance this compiles fine.

```
List<?> objectList = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
objectList = stringList;
```