# Why am I unable to cast bounded Java generics to a superclass with similar types?

Tags: java, oop, generics

Consider the following Java Generics layout where I would expect ItemList to have a compatible interface to List:

```java
    public interface ItemList<T extends Item> extends List<T> {}

    public interface Item {}

    public interface List<T> {}

    public static class Test<T extends Item> {

        public void foo(ItemList<T> fizz) {
            // T extends B
            // fizz is A<T extends B> extends C<T extends B>
            // therefore, is fizz not always compatible with C<B>?

            // bar(fizz); error?
            bar((List<Item>) fizz); // allowed, but unchecked cast warning?
        }

        private void bar(List<Item> buzz) {}
    }
```

I.e. Why am I unable to pass `fizz` to the `bar` method and why am I being warned of an unchecked cast? Is this guaranteed to be a safe cast, or is the warning a legitimate issue?

Comment: Who's on first? LOL Getting lost in the short class names and complicated family tree!

Comment: It doesn't compile because `T` can be a subtype of `B` and Java's generics are [invariant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18666878/1553851).

Comment: Sorry! I boiled it down as much as I could but couldn't find a shorter example.

Comment: You might want that to say `private void bar(List<? extends Item> buzz)`, since a `List<T>` is not a `List<Item>`.  For example, if `S` is another subtype of `Item`, then you can add an `S` to a `List<Item>` but not to a `List<T>`.

Comment: `List<Item> buzz` would allow us to add *any* `Item` like `buzz.add(new YellowItem())`,  but when you also have lets say `List<RedItem> redItems` (where `RedItem` is subtype of `Item`) should we be able to assign `buzz = redItems;`? This would allow you to add any item to `redItem`, not only red ones. For more info see [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why are Java generics not implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2745265)