# Java - Why is generic subtyping not allowed but subtyping of arrays is allowed

Tags: java, arrays, generics, subtyping

In java generic subtyping is not allowed which means this will not work -

```
List<String> ls = new ArrayList<String>(); 
List<Object> lo = ls;
```

That is so that things like this can't be carried out and would not cause run time errors -

```
lo.add(new Object());
String s = ls.get(0);
```

But then if you tried -

```
String a[] = {"see","biscuit","teleport"};
Object b [] = a;
```

It would work even though arrays would still be affected by the same problem of possible run time errors -

```
b[0] = new Integer(33);
```

That would throw an ArrayStoreException at runtime.
My question is is there a particular reason why sub typing is allowed with arrays but not generics or this is just a fault that can be fixed by stopping array sub typing from working?

Comment: [Why are arrays covariant but generics are invariant?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18666710), [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why are Java generics not implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2745265)

Comment: Completely unrelated, yet important: the `Integer` constructor is deprecated in newer Java versions. Use `valueOf` instead. This also leverages the Integer cache.