# What makes the use of bounded wildcard parameterized types possible in an array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, generics, wildcard, parameterized-types

What makes it possible to add a Pair<String, String> when I'm only extending the class Number ? Does't this violate the expectation that an array should only hold elements of the same type ?

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Pair<? extends Number, ? extends Number>[] arr = new Pair[2];
        
        m1(arr);
        
        arr[1] = new Pair<Integer, Integer>(1, 1);
        
        System.out.println(arr[0].x);
        System.out.println(arr.getClass().getComponentType());
        
    }
    
    static void m1(Object[] arr) {
        arr[0] = new Pair<String, String>("test","test");
    }
    
    
}

class Pair<T, E> {
    
    public T x;
    public E y;
    
    public Pair(T x, E y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. `Double` and `Integer` are both [`Number`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html)(s). Also, you could have a `Pair<Double, Integer>` - this `Pair` type is also known as a *tuple*.

Answer (score 0):

We have the following situation: inheritance in Java is on multiple levels, not just on 2 levels.

- class Object
- class Number (extends Object)
- class Integer extends Number
- class Double extends Number

Relations:

- Number, Integer, Double are Objects
- Integer, Double are Numbers
- Integer, Double are Objects

So an `Integer` IS a `Number`, just with some additional functionality. Same for `Double`.
If you tell the array (define, declare) to hold `Number`s, by writing either `List<Number> list` or `List(? extends Number) list` (so `Number` or any subclass thereof), then you can add any `Number`.

If you created an array of `Number`s like this: `arr[0] = new Double(2.0);` (initialize and assign) then the new value is a `Double`, but `Double` is a `Number`, so the new value also is still a `Number`. So this is totally valid.

In your case, you create an array of `Pair`s of `Number`s, making the whole thing a little more convoluted, but the basic principle remains the same: The "declared" type is still `Number` for all of them, but the assigned value is `Double` or `Integer` (which are still also `Number`s). You could still sort this out later by `instanceOf` checks to see what different subtypes the values are, if need be.

Comment: I updated the code. Now I can also use String instead of Double or Integer and violate the <? extends Number> parameter

Comment: Well now you changed your strategy to another problem. "upcasting" `Pair<? extends Number, ? extends Number>[] arr` to `Object[]` still is valid. And any `Object[]`-related operations on `arr` are now allowed by the compiler. But by doing this (writing unclean code) you will later on get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.lang.Number (java.lang.String and java.lang.Number are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')` once you try to access type information on the contents of `Pair` or most class-related ops.

Answer (score 0):

This is one example of the **array covariance** plus **type erasure** in Java.

#### Array covariance

Arrays in Java are covariant: if an array can handle Integer (`Integer[]`), and Integer is an Object, then this array can also handle Object, so it can be referenced as `Object[]`. Since String is also an Object, things get tricky! (read further [here](https://dzone.com/articles/covariance-and-contravariance) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666710/why-are-arrays-covariant-but-generics-are-invariant)).

#### Type Erasure

The correctness of the generics types is checked at compile-time, and then forgotten/erased at runtime. A `Pair<Double, Double>` is just a `Pair` at runtime. That's why if you can trick the compiler, as you did introducing the `m1()` method, then you are ok at runtime. (read further [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-type-erasure)).

#### Your code explained

Your `arr` variable is described as `Pair<? extends Number, ? extends Number>[]`. But remember that variables are just a name that references some object. The actual object behind it is just an array of Pair (`Pair[]`).

When you call `m1()`, another variable is used to reference this very same array, but this time it's a more general variable that handle any array of objects (`Object[]`).

You see that the actual array created in the `main` method is compatible with both types of the variables used to reference it throughout the code.

To overcome the **array covariance**, you could choose to use an `ArrayList` (or any other Collection you wish), but then, as you see, you would still have the generic **type erasure** problem on the `Pair` objects. like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Pair<? extends Number, ? extends Number>> arr = 
        new ArrayList<Pair<? extends Number, ? extends Number>>(); 
        
    m1(arr);
        
    arr.add(new Pair<Integer, Integer>(1, 1));
    ...               
}
    
static void m1(List arr) {
    arr.add(new Pair<String, String>("test","test"));
}
```

What a maze, uh?!

Comment: check the updated code. I was able to violate `? extends Number`

Comment: wow, that changes the focus of the question a little bit. i will try to update the answer accordingly.