# Parameter to pass in for type Class<T[]>

Tags: java, class, generics, casting, stack

I am trying to make a generic Stack class as shown

```
public class Stack<T> {
    public Stack(Class<T[]> type, int capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
        array = type.cast(Array.newInstance(type,capacity));
    }
}
```

but am unsure of what to put in for type when instantiating since I thought of doing

```
MyClass[] c = new MyClass[0];
myStack = new Stack<MyClass>(c.getClass(), 100);
```

however I get the following error of

```
Required type: Class <MyClass[]>
Provided: Class <capture of ? extends MyClass[]>
```

so I thought of using

```
c.getClass().cast()\
```

but I am unsure of what to put inside of cast() since it won't take

```
Class<MyClass[]>
```

now I am stuck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The overall design of this implementation is brittle. We are mixing two language constructs: arrays and generics. These two constructs differ in two major ways: arrays are covariant and retained, while generics are invariant and erased (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666710/why-are-arrays-covariant-but-generics-are-invariant) by [eagertoLearn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2708477/eagertolearn) as to why). Mixing both is a recipe for disaster.
Furthermore, we need the component type to call [`Array::newInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance(java.lang.Class,int)). Right now, we pass along the container-type.

I would recommend to use an `Object[]` as backing data structure and make the accessors generic to guarantee type-safety. This is also the approach taken by [`ArrayList`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java). This approach will result in (at least) one unchecked cast that cannot be avoided. I leave it to the reader to

- find the unchecked cast in `ArrayList`
- argue why the cast is rectified and will never result in an actual `ClassCastException` as long as the interal array is never leaked.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to a typed array by adding `[]` after the class name:

```java
myStack = new Stack<MyClass>(MyClass[].class, 100);
```

Comment: OP uses `c.getClass()` (which should be equivalent to `MyClass[].class`). Can you explain why your solution works, while OP's solution does not?

Comment: [`Array.newInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance-java.lang.Class-int-) requires the *component type*, so this will most probably not work as expected.

Comment: Thanks it does work, not sure why I didn't think of using .class instead of getClass() in the first place. I must have assumed they are practically the same when they are clearly not!!

Comment: @Turing85: Because `c.getClass()` has type `Class<? extends MyClass[]>`, due to the fact that `c`'s actual runtime class might be a subclass of `MyClass[]`. On the other hand, `MyClass[].class` has type `Class<MyClass[]>`.