# ClassCastException in List.toArray()

Tags: java

Can someone explain to me:

```
List<String> wordsList = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("one");
list.add("two");
list.add("three");
String[] wordsArray = (String[]) wordsList.toArray();
```

This fall with:     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;

```
 List<String> wordsList = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three");        
 String[] wordsArray = (String[]) wordsList.toArray();
```

Now is OK! What is the difference??

Comment: Your second code throws the exception too. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: Your code does not compile because there no identifier `list` is declared.

Answer (score 2):

`toArray()` is the old way of doing things, back in I think 1.5 the preferred way is to use `toArray(T[])`

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("one");
list.add("two");
list.add("three");
String [] words = list.toArray(new String[] {});
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words));
```

Comment: The preferred way today would be `list.toArray(String[]::new)`.

Comment: @DavidConrad fair enough.  I'm still learning the newer features and many of the projects I'm on mandate a lower compile level so I don't get into the habit of using the newer features.  It's aggravating.

Comment: I feel your pain. My company is using Java 8. I use recent versions on my own to keep up with the newer features.

Answer (score 0):

[`List.toArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray--) returns an `Object[]`. This type cannot, in general, be cast down to a `String[]`. In fact, no guarantee is made that it *is* a `String[]`. In your `Arrays.asList` example, it looks like `List<String>` was able to take the existing array you passed it and make a (runtime) `String[]`, but that's an implementation detail and is subject to change at any time (and, based on the comments, is not even consistent across Java versions).

The reason the function returns an `Object[]` rather than a `T[]` is because [of type erasure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java). The type `T` is not available at runtime, so we can't construct instances of `T` or `T[]`. However, there's [an overload of `toArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray-T:A-) which will put the values into a `T[]`, but *you* have to supply the array. This gets around the problem of not being able to write `new T[]`, since it's your job as the caller to supply the array, so no new allocation needs to take place.

```
String[] tmpArray = new String[10]; // Just an initial guess as to the size
String[] wordsArray = list.toArray(tmpArray); // Note: No cast necessary
```

`wordsArray` might be the same as `tmpArray`, or it might be an extended data structure constructed *from* `tmpArray`. Either way, the original `tmpArray` should be regarded as destroyed at that point and not used anymore.

**Note:** The fact that `String[]` is even a subtype of `Object[]` (i.e. that the cast you suggested *ever* works) is a consequence of a [questionable decision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666710/why-are-arrays-covariant-but-generics-are-invariant) that the Java team made to make arrays covariant, when really a mutable data structure like that should be invariant, mathematically speaking.