# List<String> when passed as argument is not getting resolved as List<Object> parameter

Tags: java, inheritance, java-8

I came across a weird runtime problem during development. I've simplified the problem here.

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> listOfString = ImmutableList.of("a", "s");
    List<Object> listOfObject = ImmutableList.of("a", "s");
    System.out.println("listOfObject = " +  test(listOfObject));
    System.out.println("listOfString = " +  test(listOfString));
  }
  public static String test(List<Object> a){
    return "List"+ a;
  }
  public static String test(Object a){
    return "Object"+ a;
  }
}
```

I expected both method calls to call the test(List<Object>) method. But that is not the case.
The output I receive is

```
listOfObject = List[a, s]
listOfString = Object[a, s]
```

From the output, I can infer that the listOfString is being treated as an Object, not a List.
I need to know why this is happening.
Thanks for the help

Comment: A `List<String>` is **not** a subtype of `List<Object>`. Try changing your method to `public static String test(List<? extends Object> a){` or just `public static String test(List<?> a){`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bit of trickiness here.

If you have a `List<String> myList`, it doesn't match a method `List<Object>`, but it does match a method with `Object` only. That's why you get the result you are experiencing.

## What can you do about it?

If you wanted to match a method with a List, you can use a wildcard, e.g:

```java
public static String test(List<?> a){
    return "List"+ a;
}
```

then if you run your code:

```java
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    List<Object> listOfObject = List.of("a", "s");
    System.out.println("listOfObject = " +  test(listOfObject));
    List<String> listOfString = List.of("a", "s");
    System.out.println("listOfString = " +  test(listOfString));
  }
  public static String test(List<?> a){
    return "List"+ a;
  }
  public static String test(Object a){
    return "Object"+ a;
  }
}
```

It will print `List`.
[image: result]

Also, I removed `LmmutableList` from guava, because there is a native alternative from Java itself `List.of("x", "y")`, but that's not relevant for the answer.

## Relevant reading

You can read more in:

- here: [Why are arrays covariant but generics are invariant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666710/why-are-arrays-covariant-but-generics-are-invariant)
- and here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html