# Type mismatch with Array of Array in Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, types

I'm trying to build an array of an array to give it as a argument to a method. 
The value of inner arrays are any kind of data (AnyVal) such as Int or Double.

The method's signature is as follows:

```
def plot[T <: AnyVal](config:Map[String, String], data:Array[Array[T]]): Unit = {
```

This is the code:

```
val array1 = (1 to 10).toArray
val array2 = ArrayBuffer[Int]()
array1.foreach { i =>
  array2 += (getSize(summary, i))
}
val array3 = new Array[Int](summary.getSize())

val arrays = ArrayBuffer[Array[AnyVal]](array1, array2.toArray, array3) # <-- ERROR1
Gnuplotter.plot(smap, arrays.toArray) # <-- ERROR2
```

However, I have two errors:

[image]
[image]

What might be wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Array`, being a mutable data structure, is not covariant ([here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6684534/846273))

So `Array[Int]` is not a subtype of `Array[AnyVal]`, hence you cannot pass it where an `Array[AnyVal]` is expected.

Would a `List` do for you purposes?

In case performance matters and you really need to use `Array`, you can simply cast everything to an `Array[Any]` and be done with it.

Alternatively, if you just need an `Array[Any]` as the final type to pass to the `plot` function, you can do everything with `List`, and convert it with `toArray[Any]` at the very end.

Comment: s/Int/AnyVal you mean? Of course, upcasting is a solution, kind of a ugly one though. Unless performance is crucial I would just avoid using mutable data structures

Comment: well, calling `toArray[Any]` at the very end is always an option

Comment: as always, it's a tradeoff. Unless performance is not an critical issue (in which case you would care about integer boxing), I very much prefer working with an immutable collection, rather than casting everything to `Any`. In the OP example, `Int` boxing isn't going to make any significant difference.

Comment: I guess w/o specialization you box anyway. Which I guess is obvious.