# Type mismatch between Any and String in Scala

Tags: scala, type-mismatch

```
def foo(x : Array[Any]) = println(x.length);
foo(Array[String]("test", "test"));
```

This code will raise error message:

```
:6: error: type mismatch;

found   : Array[String]

 required: Array[Any]
       foo(Array[String]("test", "test"))
```

All classes in Scala directly or indirectly inherit from Any class. So String is Any. Why we cannot pass an Array[String] to the foo method?

Comment: Hint: arrays are *invariant* on type of its argument. `String` is `Any` but `Array[String]` is not `Array[Any]`. Try `def foo[T](x: Array[T])` instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are Arrays invariant, but Lists covariant?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684493/why-are-arrays-invariant-but-lists-covariant)

Comment: Thanks!@dmitry @cchantep

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Arrays are invariant on type of its argument, which means that `String` is `Any`, but `Array[String]` is not `Array[Any]`.

`def foo[T](x: Array[T])` or `def foo(x: Array[_])` will both work.

Comment: just for curiosity: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684493/why-are-arrays-invariant-but-lists-covariant