# Scala F-Bounded Type Polymorphism

Tags: scala, scala-collections

```
trait Account[T <: Account[T]]

case class BrokerAccount(total:BigDecimal) extends Account[BrokerAccount]
case class SavingsAccount(total:BigDecimal) extends Account[SavingsAccount]
```

Below function declaration and invocation works fine.

```
def foo1( xs: Array[T forSome { type T <: Account[T] }]):Array[T forSome { type T <: Account[T] }] = xs
foo1(Array(BrokerAccount(100),SavingsAccount(50)))
```

But below invocation gives compilation error.

```
def foo2( xs: List[T forSome { type T <: Account[T] }]):List[T forSome { type T <: Account[T] }] = xs
foo2(List(BrokerAccount(100),SavingsAccount(50)))
```

Error

> Main.scala:14: error: type mismatch;
>   found   : List[Product with Serializable with Main.Account[_ >: Main.SavingsAccount with Main.BrokerAccount <: Product with Serializable with Main.Account[_ >: Main.SavingsAccount with Main.BrokerAccount <: Product with Serializable]]]
>   required: List[T forSome { type T <: Main.Account[T] }] foo2(List(BrokerAccount(100),SavingsAccount(50)))

Can someone please explain me why compilation error occur in later case?

Answer (score 3):

The key to the problem is variance - you're trying to return a contravariant value in covariant position (function return type).
Despite `List` type is covariant in its argument (`trait List[+A]`), this essentially means its values are contravariant (can be assigned to a List of supertypes):

```
val listOfSupers: List[_ >: Account[_]] = List(BrokerAccount(100), SavingsAccount(50))
```

What you're trying to return from the function `foo2` is a complete contrary - `List[_ <: Account[_]]`, thus the compiler error.

If instead of `List` you use `Set` there, which is invariant in its type parameter just like `Array`, everything will work fine.

Comment: How can below line compiles then?   foo2( List[T forSome { type T <: Account[T] }](BrokerAccount(100),SavingsAccount(50)))

Comment: For more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684493/why-are-arrays-invariant-but-lists-covariant